# × Unhandled Rejection (Error): A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a logout link in React using context hooks and reducer dispatch. I'm getting an error after i log-in.

I'm using node, express, and mongoose in the backend.

**Here is Logout.js:**

```js
import React ,{useState, useContext}from 'react';
import {useHistory,Redirect, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthContext } from '../../contexts/AuthContext';
import axios from 'axios'

const Logout =()=>{
    const {authLog,dispatch} = useContext(AuthContext)
 axios.get('http://localhost:2000/apiEndpoint/CREATE/user/logout',{withCredentials:true}).then((res)=>{
     
      if(res.data==='Logout Success'){
        dispatch({type: 'LOGOUT'});
        
      }
  }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err)
  })
    

    return(
        <div >
            <h1>You are logged out!!!!</h1>
            {<Redirect to='/' />}
        </div>
        
    )
}


export default Logout
```

**Here is AuthReducer.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';

const AuthReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "LOGIN":
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(action.payload.user));
        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(action.payload.token));
        return {
          ...state,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          user: action.payload.user,
          token: action.payload.token
        };
        
      case "LOGOUT":
        localStorage.clear();
        return {
          ...state,
          isAuthenticated: false,
          user: null
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

export default AuthReducer
```

**Here is Blog.js:**
**[NOTE]**: I'm getting an error after the login page when it redirects me to the Blog.js component after successful login.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ArticleCard from '../ArticleCard'
import '../CSS/Blog.css'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
const axios = require('axios').default;

class Blog extends Component{
    state={
        }
    


        
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='blog-grid'>
                <div className='ninetyPer'>
                
                <ArticleCard />

                </div>
                <div className='tenPer'>
                <Sidebar />
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
        )
    }
}


export default Blog
```

**Here is Sidebar.js**:

```js
import React ,{useState, useContext}from 'react';
import {useHistory,Redirect, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthContext } from '../../contexts/AuthContext';
import '../CSS/Sidebar.css'




const Sidebar =()=>{

    const {authLog,dispatch} = useContext(AuthContext)


    var userOBJ=(authLog.isAuthenticated)?(JSON.parse(authLog.user.userLocal)):null;
    
    console.log('AuthLOg:',userOBJ)

    return(
        <div className='sidebar'>
            
            {userOBJ!=null?(<h4>Hello {userOBJ.username}!</h4>):(<h4>You are not logged in</h4>)}
            {authLog.isAuthenticated?(<Link to='/user/logout'><h5>Logout</h5></Link>):''}
            <hr />
        </div>
    )
}


export default Sidebar
```

***In the browser console, there are 3 error including the one in the title:***

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Sidebar (Sidebar.js:14)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at react-dom.development.js:11089
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11084)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11072)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21199)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:15660)
    at Login.js:39
index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <Sidebar> component:
    in Sidebar (at Blog.js:29)
    in div (at Blog.js:28)
    in div (at Blog.js:21)
    in Blog (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:43)
    in AuthContextProvider (at App.js:38)
    in Switch (at App.js:37)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:33)
    in div (at App.js:31)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit //fbReactLink to learn more about error boundaries.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
react-dom.development.js:248 Uncaught (in promise) Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See //fbReactLink for more information.
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:248)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at react-dom.development.js:11089
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11084)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11072)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21199)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:15660)
    at Login.js:39
```

If you need me to post the other components as well please do let me know and I will update this post.

Answer (score 0):

A cross-origin error occurs when the server is being accessed through a port or host other than itself (React rather than localhost or [www.websitename.com](http://www.websitename.com))

To quickly fix this, add this to your React package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:2000"
```

You can now access the server files using "/" instead of "http://localhost:2000" as React is using the proxy instead of an external link.

Your code in Logout.js line 7 should now be:

```
axios.get('/apiEndpoint/CREATE/user/logout',{withCredentials:true}).then((res)=>{
```

Just remember to change your proxy when in development to whatever your base website name is E.G. ([www.website.com](http://www.website.com))

EDIT: for convenience, the Logout.js full code can be replaced with:

```
import React ,{useState, useContext}from 'react';
import {useHistory,Redirect, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthContext } from '../../contexts/AuthContext';
import axios from 'axios'

const Logout =()=>{
    const {authLog,dispatch} = useContext(AuthContext)
 axios.get('/apiEndpoint/CREATE/user/logout',{withCredentials:true}).then((res)=>{
     
      if(res.data==='Logout Success'){
        dispatch({type: 'LOGOUT'});
        
      }
  }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err)
  })
    

    return(
        <div >
            <h1>You are logged out!!!!</h1>
            {<Redirect to='/' />}
        </div>
        
    )
}


export default Logout
```

If this doesn't work, try our the cars npm package at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Simply import it and run the function right after initializing app as follows

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

IMPORTANT NOTE -- make sure to pass in an object like this {origin: YOUR_REACT_LOCALHOST_URI} when using cors in production.
You can read up on this in the cors npm docs.

Comment: Thanks for replying but sadly that didn't work. I'm getting the exact same errors.

Comment: just updated with an alternate solution. Pay attention to the note at the bottom

Comment: I have tried it. I already have origin set to true in cors. Thanks.